# Is there any format description compatible with Java and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

In Java there is `DecimalFormat` which supports

- `###.##`  -> 3.14
- `0` -> 3
- `00.000` -> 03.142
- `#.##%` -> 314.16%
- `pie is ###.##` -> pie is 3.14

but I cannot find an equivalent function in Swift for iOS.

There is  `NumberFormatter`, but that does not support `pie is ###.##`, and setting all properties in code is inconvenient:

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.numberStyle = .currencyAccounting
```

I am curious about if there is a format both supported by Java & Swift, that will be very useful in React Native (define the format in js)

Comment: Can you change to simply use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))?

Comment: Why can't you support "pie is 3.14"? You can ask NSNumberFormatter for a string and you can concatenation that with "pie is".

Comment: @kennytm , that make sense. although in js config "pie is ###.##" is clearer than "pie is %.2f%"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(NS)NumberFormatter` has `positiveFormat` and `negativeFormat`
properties, which are format patterns according to the [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-numbers.html#Number_Format_Patterns). These seem to be compatible
with the Java `DecimalFormat`.

Examples:

```
let posNumber = NSNumber(value: Double.pi)
let negNumber = NSNumber(value: -Double.pi)

let f1 = NumberFormatter()
f1.positiveFormat = "00.000"
print(f1.string(from: posNumber)!) // 03.142
print(f1.string(from: negNumber)!) // -03.142

let f2 = NumberFormatter()
f2.positiveFormat = "pie is ###.## "
print(f2.string(from: posNumber)!) // pie is 3.14
```

The numbers are formatted according to the current locale (so the output
can be `3,14` as well). If that is not intended, add

```
f2.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

If you don't set `negativeFormat` then the positive format with
a prepended minus sign will be used for negative numbers.
That works well in the first example, but not with custom text:

```
print(f2.string(from: negNumber)!) // -pie is 3.14
```

This is solved by setting both the positive and negative format:

```
let f3 = NumberFormatter()
f3.positiveFormat = "Result is 00.000"
f3.negativeFormat = "Result is -00.000"
print(f3.string(from: posNumber)!) // Result is 03.142
print(f3.string(from: negNumber)!) // Result is -03.142
```

On macOS, the `format` property can be used instead, positive
and (optional) negative format are separated by a semicolon.
In the above examples that would be:

```
f2.format = "pie is ###.##"

f3.format = "Result is 00.000;Result is -00.000"
```